# Javascript- Background scrolling slower when there is more content on the webpage on different screen resolutions

Tags: javascript

I made a webpage and wanted to have the background move slower when scrolling, so that the whole background image is fully visible. When I add content to that webpage the total scrolling height changes. So I made a calculation that slows down the scrolling speed when there is more content.

It works when I tested it on my 1920x1080 screen.
When I tested it on different screen resolutions it did not work properly anymore. The background repeated itself on the top causing a weird transition. I tried to make changes to the calculations but I did not get it to work.
How can I prevent that transition from happening on other screen resolutions?

```js
function calcParallax(tileheight, speedratio, scrollposition) 
{
  return ((tileheight) - (Math.floor(scrollposition / speedratio) % (tileheight+1)));
}

window.onload = function() {
  window.onscroll = function() {
    

    var posY = (document.documentElement.scrollTop) ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : window.pageYOffset;
    
    var ground = document.getElementById('ground');
  

 var body = document.body,
    html = document.documentElement;

 var webheight = Math.max( body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, 
                      html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight );  
   

   //10001 is the scroll length of page where you need a speedratio of 5.7 to see the full background image. 
   //This only works on 1920x1080
 var speedratio = webheight * 5.7 / 10001;
   

   //2670 is the height of the background image.
    var groundparallax = calcParallax(2670, speedratio, posY);
    ground.style.backgroundPosition = "0 " + groundparallax + "px"; 

  };

};
```

```css
body
{
  height: 100%;    
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

#ground {
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.pageContentBox
{  
    margin-left: 170px;
 margin-right: 170px;
 background-color: rgba(57, 57, 57, 0.5);
}

.pageContent
{  

 margin-left: 50px;
 margin-right: 50px;
 color: white;
}
```

```html
<body id='ground' background="https://i.imgur.com/Yljakhv.jpg">

<div class= pageContentBox align="centre">
<div class= pageContent align="centre">

<h1>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras et urna ultrices felis sagittis bibendum. Proin mattis faucibus augue. Aliquam eu erat ac orci pretium tempor sit amet eget ex. Fusce eget pharetra turpis. Ut tristique aliquet ligula, quis iaculis sem. Phasellus tempus imperdiet felis. Donec sit amet lacinia purus. In vitae tincidunt ante, nec feugiat odio. Integer ultrices sem sed finibus porttitor. Vestibulum egestas vehicula ultricies. Morbi vehicula urna ut ipsum sodales porta. Mauris turpis nisi, imperdiet eget feugiat vitae, hendrerit eu massa. Vestibulum luctus sit amet turpis at condimentum. Suspendisse in est ultrices, facilisis nisl vestibulum, sollicitudin justo. Curabitur ultricies malesuada purus eu viverra. Phasellus interdum venenatis porttitor.

Mauris fringilla vulputate iaculis. Nunc urna lectus, varius quis pharetra at, fringilla a erat. Maecenas mollis orci sed enim sagittis, sit amet dignissim nibh pellentesque. Vivamus laoreet ultrices urna, ut blandit enim. Ut volutpat arcu interdum mi placerat tempor. Sed placerat lacus lectus, vitae placerat neque scelerisque vitae. Morbi semper lobortis eros. Maecenas semper, magna ac fringilla rhoncus, est urna suscipit ante, bibendum sodales urna lectus id turpis. Vivamus semper justo sed ligula dictum, non scelerisque tortor consectetur. Integer metus tellus, posuere eget nisl ac, fermentum sodales diam. Nunc tincidunt laoreet mauris, sed pharetra nulla ultrices at. Curabitur vel est massa.

Donec eu imperdiet nulla. Pellentesque tristique semper congue. Pellentesque iaculis ut ligula quis efficitur. Fusce nec nisi pulvinar nisl suscipit pharetra. Nunc ac varius augue. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. In sem augue, euismod a leo in, laoreet imperdiet magna. Etiam pellentesque eros magna, quis viverra nunc laoreet in.

Donec ut varius ante. Nunc tristique, tellus feugiat fringilla mattis, ante augue vehicula mi, at elementum massa nibh nec erat. Phasellus euismod, metus non vulputate imperdiet, ante lacus laoreet augue, ut condimentum tortor enim at augue. Donec congue et dolor vel maximus. Sed volutpat orci eget dui blandit, at laoreet nisl dapibus. Nunc vitae interdum dui. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Proin ipsum dui, bibendum ac faucibus mattis, pharetra id enim. Morbi faucibus ante id lacus consectetur, ut commodo neque molestie.

Pellentesque convallis blandit accumsan. Quisque non nunc ac massa venenatis blandit nec a nisl. Ut iaculis sagittis lectus. Donec ut porta nisi. Integer eget venenatis nibh. Nulla et interdum augue. Mauris non gravida nisi, et imperdiet ante. Cras convallis aliquam ullamcorper. Cras malesuada scelerisque justo, pretium sagittis quam dignissim quis. Curabitur tempus porta hendrerit. Morbi at varius risus. Proin elementum, erat nec auctor maximus, elit mauris accumsan dolor, et hendrerit nulla diam vitae quam. Aliquam malesuada sollicitudin arcu eu porta. Suspendisse eget massa massa. Curabitur et urna placerat, molestie justo in, mollis dolor.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras et urna ultrices felis sagittis bibendum. Proin mattis faucibus augue. Aliquam eu erat ac orci pretium tempor sit amet eget ex. Fusce eget pharetra turpis. Ut tristique aliquet ligula, quis iaculis sem. Phasellus tempus imperdiet felis. Donec sit amet lacinia purus. In vitae tincidunt ante, nec feugiat odio. Integer ultrices sem sed finibus porttitor. Vestibulum egestas vehicula ultricies. Morbi vehicula urna ut ipsum sodales porta. Mauris turpis nisi, imperdiet eget feugiat vitae, hendrerit eu massa. Vestibulum luctus sit amet turpis at condimentum. Suspendisse in est ultrices, facilisis nisl vestibulum, sollicitudin justo. Curabitur ultricies malesuada purus eu viverra. Phasellus interdum venenatis porttitor.

Mauris fringilla vulputate iaculis. Nunc urna lectus, varius quis pharetra at, fringilla a erat. Maecenas mollis orci sed enim sagittis, sit amet dignissim nibh pellentesque. Vivamus laoreet ultrices urna, ut blandit enim. Ut volutpat arcu interdum mi placerat tempor. Sed placerat lacus lectus, vitae placerat neque scelerisque vitae. Morbi semper lobortis eros. Maecenas semper, magna ac fringilla rhoncus, est urna suscipit ante, bibendum sodales urna lectus id turpis. Vivamus semper justo sed ligula dictum, non scelerisque tortor consectetur. Integer metus tellus, posuere eget nisl ac, fermentum sodales diam. Nunc tincidunt laoreet mauris, sed pharetra nulla ultrices at. Curabitur vel est massa.

Donec eu imperdiet nulla. Pellentesque tristique semper congue. Pellentesque iaculis ut ligula quis efficitur. Fusce nec nisi pulvinar nisl suscipit pharetra. Nunc ac varius augue. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. In sem augue, euismod a leo in, laoreet imperdiet magna. Etiam pellentesque eros magna, quis viverra nunc laoreet in.

Donec ut varius ante. Nunc tristique, tellus feugiat fringilla mattis, ante augue vehicula mi, at elementum massa nibh nec erat. Phasellus euismod, metus non vulputate imperdiet, ante lacus laoreet augue, ut condimentum tortor enim at augue. Donec congue et dolor vel maximus. Sed volutpat orci eget dui blandit, at laoreet nisl dapibus. Nunc vitae interdum dui. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Proin ipsum dui, bibendum ac faucibus mattis, pharetra id enim. Morbi faucibus ante id lacus consectetur, ut commodo neque molestie.

Pellentesque convallis blandit accumsan. Quisque non nunc ac massa venenatis blandit nec a nisl. Ut iaculis sagittis lectus. Donec ut porta nisi. Integer eget venenatis nibh. Nulla et interdum augue. Mauris non gravida nisi, et imperdiet ante. Cras convallis aliquam ullamcorper. Cras malesuada scelerisque justo, pretium sagittis quam dignissim quis. Curabitur tempus porta hendrerit. Morbi at varius risus. Proin elementum, erat nec auctor maximus, elit mauris accumsan dolor, et hendrerit nulla diam vitae quam. Aliquam malesuada sollicitudin arcu eu porta. Suspendisse eget massa massa. Curabitur et urna placerat, molestie justo in, mollis dolor.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras et urna ultrices felis sagittis bibendum. Proin mattis faucibus augue. Aliquam eu erat ac orci pretium tempor sit amet eget ex. Fusce eget pharetra turpis. Ut tristique aliquet ligula, quis iaculis sem. Phasellus tempus imperdiet felis. Donec sit amet lacinia purus. In vitae tincidunt ante, nec feugiat odio. Integer ultrices sem sed finibus porttitor. Vestibulum egestas vehicula ultricies. Morbi vehicula urna ut ipsum sodales porta. Mauris turpis nisi, imperdiet eget feugiat vitae, hendrerit eu massa. Vestibulum luctus sit amet turpis at condimentum. Suspendisse in est ultrices, facilisis nisl vestibulum, sollicitudin justo. Curabitur ultricies malesuada purus eu viverra. Phasellus interdum venenatis porttitor.

Mauris fringilla vulputate iaculis. Nunc urna lectus, varius quis pharetra at, fringilla a erat. Maecenas mollis orci sed enim sagittis, sit amet dignissim nibh pellentesque. Vivamus laoreet ultrices urna, ut blandit enim. Ut volutpat arcu interdum mi placerat tempor. Sed placerat lacus lectus, vitae placerat neque scelerisque vitae. Morbi semper lobortis eros. Maecenas semper, magna ac fringilla rhoncus, est urna suscipit ante, bibendum sodales urna lectus id turpis. Vivamus semper justo sed ligula dictum, non scelerisque tortor consectetur. Integer metus tellus, posuere eget nisl ac, fermentum sodales diam. Nunc tincidunt laoreet mauris, sed pharetra nulla ultrices at. Curabitur vel est massa.

Donec eu imperdiet nulla. Pellentesque tristique semper congue. Pellentesque iaculis ut ligula quis efficitur. Fusce nec nisi pulvinar nisl suscipit pharetra. Nunc ac varius augue. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. In sem augue, euismod a leo in, laoreet imperdiet magna. Etiam pellentesque eros magna, quis viverra nunc laoreet in.

Donec ut varius ante. Nunc tristique, tellus feugiat fringilla mattis, ante augue vehicula mi, at elementum massa nibh nec erat. Phasellus euismod, metus non vulputate imperdiet, ante lacus laoreet augue, ut condimentum tortor enim at augue. Donec congue et dolor vel maximus. Sed volutpat orci eget dui blandit, at laoreet nisl dapibus. Nunc vitae interdum dui. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Proin ipsum dui, bibendum ac faucibus mattis, pharetra id enim. Morbi faucibus ante id lacus consectetur, ut commodo neque molestie.

Pellentesque convallis blandit accumsan. Quisque non nunc ac massa venenatis blandit nec a nisl. Ut iaculis sagittis lectus. Donec ut porta nisi. Integer eget venenatis nibh. Nulla et interdum augue. Mauris non gravida nisi, et imperdiet ante. Cras convallis aliquam ullamcorper. Cras malesuada scelerisque justo, pretium sagittis quam dignissim quis. Curabitur tempus porta hendrerit. Morbi at varius risus. Proin elementum, erat nec auctor maximus, elit mauris accumsan dolor, et hendrerit nulla diam vitae quam. Aliquam malesuada sollicitudin arcu eu porta. Suspendisse eget massa massa. Curabitur et urna placerat, molestie justo in, mollis dolor.

</h1>


</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In browser all html rendering and executing javascript is running on **main-thread** so animation performance will degraded

*(if you are using animation property that running on main-thread , also scrolling is affected by main-thread activity)*

Always use animation property that are running on **compositor-thread** e.g `transform, opacity` so animation not will affected by **main-thread**, result in smooth animation effect.

see which property will running on **compositor-thread** or on **main-thread**  [cssTrigger](https://csstriggers.com/)

Read below articles before start working on animation.

- [Css-vs-Javascript](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ux/animations/css-vs-javascript)
- [Animations-and-Performance](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ux/animations/animations-and-performance)
- [The-basics-of-Easing](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ux/animations/the-basics-of-easing)
- [Animating-between-Views](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ux/animations/animating-between-views)